# Passing istream and string as functions parameters

Tags: c++, stringstream, istream

I have the following code. What I'm trying to do is implement a word count function similar to wc in unix. It takes a file as input and gives back the number of lines, words and characters in that file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::string> split(std::istream& is, char delim){

    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::string elem;

    while(std::getline(is, elem, delim))
    {
        if(elem != "")
            result.push_back(std::move(elem));
    }
    return result;
}

std::vector< std::string> split(const std::string& val, char delim){

    std::stringstream is(val);
    return split(is, delim);
}

struct WCResult {

    std::string Name;
    std::size_t LineCount;
    std::size_t WordCount;
    std::size_t ByteCount;
    
    WCResult(const std::string& name = "", std::size_t lc = 0, std::size_t wc = 0, std::size_t bc = 0): Name(name), LineCount(lc), WordCount(wc), ByteCount(bc) 
    {}
    void output(std::ostream& os) 
    { 
        os << this->LineCount << " " << this->WordCount << " " << this->ByteCount << " " << this->Name << std::endl; 
    }
};

WCResult getWordCount(const std::istream& is, const std::string& name){

    std::stringstream is_str(is); //Error1: argument types are: (const std::istream)
    std::vector<std::string> linecount = split(is_str, '\n');
    std::vector<std::string> wordcount = split(is, ' '); //Error2: argument types are: const std::istream, char)
    std::size_t bytecount = 0;
    for(std::string str : wordcount){
        bytecount += str.size();
    }
    return WCResult{name, linecount.size(), wordcount.size(), bytecount};
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);

    std::ifstream file(args[1]);
    WCResult wc_result = getWordCount(file, args[1]);
    wc_result.output(std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to pass my file either as a string or as an input stream. It does work for the function `std::vector< std::string> split(const std::string& val, char delim)`.

Why am I getting the errors?

Error:

```
src/newwc.cpp:45:48: error: binding reference of type ‘std::istream&’ {aka ‘std::basic_istream<char>&’} to ‘const istream’ {aka ‘const std::basic_istream<char>’} discards qualifiers
   45 |     std::vector<std::string> wordcount = split(is, ' ');
      |                                                ^~
src/newwc.cpp:7:46: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > split(std::istream&, char)’
    7 | std::vector<std::string> split(std::istream& is, char delim)
```

This is the only error i get when i compile, but the I also get another error in the IDE, which seems not to get caught when compiling.

Comment: Please copy-paste the full and complete error output you get as a separate block so it's easier to see.

Comment: Use non-const istream reference as you can't do much with const stream.

Comment: Also, you can't convert a (reference to a) `std::ifstream` to a `std::stringstream` using `std::stringstream is_str(is);`

Comment: Is there a way to do that? @RemyLebeau I mean converting a 'std::ifstream' to a 'std::stringstream'

Comment: Try `std::stringstream is_str; is_str << is.rdbuf();`

Comment: @r3k0j why not just pass the `ifstream` as-is to your `split(istream&)` overload? Why waste overhead reading the entire file into a `std::stringstream first, when `split()` can read the entire file directly?